# User control not displaying from object in Windows App

Tags: c#, json.net

Currently making an app which requires to search for records and display the records from a REST api. To achieve this I created a user control which displays all the values receive

This is the code I am using right now:

```
....
 string feedback = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic Patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(feedback);

            patients.Items.Clear();
            if (Patients.results != null)
            {

                foreach (var Amountpatient in Patients.results)
                {

                    //to disply items in User control 
                    Patient patientControl = new Patient();
                    patientControl.PatientName = Amountpatient;

                    patients.Items.Add(patientControl);

                }

            }
```

On the user control this is the code I am using:

```
private dynamic PatientNames;        
public dynamic PatientName
    {
        get
        {
            return PatientNames;
        }
        set
        {

            lblName.Text = PatientNames
        }
    }
```

This problem is that no user controls get created. There is no issue with the REST api, I have checked using wireshark, and my query is getting a correct.

I have a feeling I am doing something wrong with this, initially I was using DataContracts, but that was not working either.

Comment: Why not use strongly type object here? It would make things more clrease Also. in PatientName property you are setting PatientNames to textbox directly which means PatientNames is nowhere assigned.

Comment: Sorry, just started programming in C# ~2 weeks ago. but from my understanding, i made a get; set; and sent "patientControl.PatientName = Amountpatient;" to PatientName, and set that property in the textbox (this code is somewhat copy pasted)